# Dynamic parameterization in JMH

Tags: java, jmh

Is there a @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "...") equivalent of JUnit in JMH? I am aware of @Params but it only accepts constant values. I'd like to generate the parameters dynamically.

Comment: No. But there may be some programmatic trick I'm not aware of, try searching (and then potentially asking on) [`jmh-dev`](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/). E.g. I see a similar, but not entirely the same request here: https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2016-August/002308.html

Comment: you might want to explain what you are trying to do a bit more may be? but indeed, you can pass `params` when setting up the test, like the above shows. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Upvoted. I've a similar use case where I want the parameters to be random numbers generated from a range.